# PHP change url style

Tags: php, url, iis, url-rewriting

Let's say I got a file called test.php and I can gather information by using `test.php?id=(ID)`. I'm using IIS and I've managed to remove the .php extensions from each file, so it shows `test?id=(ID)` but now I'm wondering how I would have to do if I want it to show `test/id/(ID)`.

Not quite sure what to google in this situation, that's why I'm asking here. I hope anyone can help me out a bit, all help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: You are looking for 'Url Routing'. That's a way to achive this. More infos: http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

Comment: Take a look at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template, it is usually refereed to as 'pretty urls'.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I'll be moving to apache soon, so I'll save your link.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        $source_url="http://www.url.com/xyz/test.php?id=1234";
        //to get file name
        $url_info=pathinfo("http://www.url.com/xyz/test.php?id=1234");

        if (!filter_var($source_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == false) {
            //source_url is a valid URL;
            $token_url = parse_url($source_url);
           //parameters of url
            $query = parse_url($source_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
            parse_str($query, $output);
            echo $url_info['filename']."/id/".$output['id'];
        }
        ?>
```